# jQuery: Selecting Table Columns by Index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table MyTable and I want to select column i using a loop and test if column i has a certain css class.

I tried this:

```
thestop = 4; // simplified for clarity

for (i = 0; i < thestop; i++){
   if ( $('#MyTable .th').eq(i).hasClass('MyClass') )
      { $(this).width('60'); }
}
```

For sure there are several problems with this and I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas welcome!

Thanks.

Comment: You mean, you want to select the column header cell?

Comment: What exactly is the problem if I may ask?

Comment: The problem is that the table isn't resizing the columns. I'm looping through the array because I have another array that contains widths for each of the columns that are of class MyClass. If I replace the width statement with an alert, nothing comes up.

Comment: Are you sure `this` refers to the column? As it is not located within a jQuery function, it probably refers to something else than you'd like to have it refer to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#MyTable th.MyClass').each(function(i) {
    $(this).width( arr[i] );
});
```

where `arr` is the array containing the widths.

Comment: The problem is that they're not all of width 60. I have an array that contains the widths for each column and I want to loop through each column and assign it the width of the value in the array with the corresponding index: column .MyClass[3].width = Array[3] in pseudocode

Answer (score 1):

The thing I spotted right off is that `.th` will find elemets with the *class* th, not `<th>` elements (use plain `th` for that).  Also, I'm not sure that `$(this)` is referring to the selected element in this case - I think it only behaves like that in `.each(function() {})` functions...

Anyways, I think you can do this in a pretty elegant one-liner:

```
thestop = 4;
$('#MyTable th.MyClass:lt('+thestop+')').width('60px');
```

This'll find all the `<th>`s in your table that have an index of less than `thestop` (using the [jQuery :lt selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)), and set their widths right there.  And if you actually did want things with the class 'th', just put that leading dot back in.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It does something strange: if I set tot to 4, it sets the width to 60 for the first 4 columns. It needs to set the width for column 4 only, not the first 4 columns. I'm trying too.

Comment: @frenchie  Ah - I misinterpreted the question (sorry).  You can use `:eq` instead of `:lt` - that should be what you want.  And you may need to subtract one from `thestop` when doing this...  Cheers!

Comment: no problem, I got it. Your code is still good and very elegant!